# Problema con mi visual estudio, no reconoce los proyectos cuando abro la solución

Tags: visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CUando creo un nuevo proyecto, en la solución no aparece las carpetas ni nada como en la imagen de fondo blanco, solo me sale el nombre de la solucion y dice 0 proyectos, y apesar de crear uno nuevo sigue sin aparecer nada

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.